# Plotting Triplet Points with Unique Colors for Each Point

Tags: plotting, color, eigenvalues

I have a set of eigenvalue triplets from some 3x3 matrices and I would like to plot them on the complex plane. My goal is to plot them such that each triplet has a unique color that identifies the points with one another. I believe that Mathematica does this automatically if the points are separated in such a way that

```
{{x1,x2,x3},{y1,y2,y3},{z1,z2,z3}}
```

however, I have 125 triplets that I would like to plot -- so it seems Mathematica starts to repeat colors after a handful of them. In theory, I would like to just extend what ComplexListPlot already does, just to a larger number of points.

Below is some sample code where I have provided a list of five eigenvalue triplets, however as mentioned I have 125 in the actual problem. So, my first thought was to attempt to do some sort of color gradient for the points. When I tried this with the below code, it seems to apply the color gradient to the location of the point on the plot instead of the triplet of points.

```
ComplexListPlot[eigsol, PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 0.2}, {-0.1, 0.1}}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"]
```

[image]

This produces the attached result, which is clearly not what I am looking for. So, is there any way to color a large list of triplets in such a way that it is easy to identify the points with one another?

Example Data:

```
eigsol = {{-0.150398 + 0. I, 0.0607001 + 0.0346517 I, 
  0.0607001 - 0.0346517 I}, {-0.150368 + 0. I, 0.056947 + 0.0321297 I,
   0.056947 - 0.0321297 I}, {-0.150341 + 0. I, 
  0.0537149 + 0.0294061 I, 
  0.0537149 - 0.0294061 I}, {-0.150314 + 0. I, 0.0508797 + 0.026467 I,
   0.0508797 - 0.026467 I}, {-0.15029 + 0. I, 0.0483519 + 0.0232498 I,
   0.0483519 - 0.0232498 I}}
```

I would welcome anyway to color them uniquely, it doesn't need to be a gradient as I tried (and failed) to do. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`PlotStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle) to color each set:

```
ComplexListPlot[
    eigsol,
    PlotStyle -> ColorData["Rainbow"]/@Subdivide[Length[eigsol]-1]
]
```

[image]